# Some tables are not visible but I can query them using RODBC and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

I am running R 3.0.1 and connecting to a SQL Server using RODBC. I am able to create the ODBC connection and execute queries without a problem. However, there are several different databases nested within the connection. I can query them, but cannot see the tables to get column names or other descriptives. Here's what I'm doing:

```
db_conn <- odbcConnect("db_name", "login", "pw")
sqlTables(db_conn)

TABLE_CAT    TABLE_SCHEM    TABLE_NAME    TABLE_TYPE    REMARKS
db_name_one  schema_name    table_1_name  TABLE         <NA>
```

And so on. I can see all of the tables in db_name_one, but not in db_name_two or db_name_three. However, I can query the other db_names using:

```
sqlQuery(db_conn, "select top 10 * from db_name_two.table_name")
```

With no problems. This would be great if I had all of the table and column names memorized, but obviously I don't.

Comment: What you see with sqlTables(db_conn) depends on the ODBC driver you are using. Which one are you using to make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the database name in order to see tables in that database. For example:

```
#'catalog' argument is for database names
#see tables in a database
sqlTables(db_conn, catalog = "db_name_two")
#see columns in a table of a database
sqlColumns(db_conn, catalog = "db_name_two",sqtable = "table1")
```